# FOR loop on doubly linked list doesn't return the last element. The reverse gives a segmentation fault

Tags: c, list, loops, doubly-linked-list

This is the declaration of the list:

```
 typedef struct list
 {  char let;
    struct list *next;
    struct list *prev;
 }list;
 list *start=NULL, *stop=NULL;
```

Let the test word be `Example`

The function used to create the list works as expected. I tried to printf
 `stop->let` and `stop->prev->next->let` as well as doing `start->next...->next->let` all the way to the last one just to check that every link is working. And I do get the last letter `e`.

However the following `for` loop ends right before displaying the last letter.
                 (The output is `Exampl`):

```
for(current=start;current->next!=NULL;current=current->next)
                  printf("%c",current->let);
```

Also, trying to display the words from right to left gives a segmentation fault before anything is displayed:

```
for(current=stop;current->prev!=NULL;current=current->prev)
                  printf("%c",current->let);
```

As requested, here is the function to create the list. The input is a string. After computing it's `strlen` the function creates a new node for every letter.

```
void create(list *first)

{   list* new_node, *current;
    char word[50];

printf("Please input the word: "); //read the input
scanf("%[^\n]s",&word);
for(int i=0;i<=strlen(word)-1;i++) 
{   new_node=malloc(sizeof(list));
    new_node->let=word[i];
    if(first==NULL)
    {

        start=first=current=new_node;
        current=new_node;
        new_node->prev=NULL;
    }
    else
        if(i==strlen(word)-1)
        {
            current->next=new_node;
            new_node->prev=current;
            new_node->next=NULL;
            stop=current=new_node;


        }
        else
        {
            current->next=new_node;
            new_node->prev=current;
            current=new_node;
        }

}
```

Note:

1.`start->prev` as well as `stop->next` are `NULL` after the list is created.

2.The exact same `for` loop works perfectly for the singly linked list.

3.`list *current` is a local variable of the displaying function.

Comment: `for(current=first;current->next!=NULL;current=current->next)` should be `for(current=first;current!=NULL;current=current->next)`

Comment: Note: `start as well as stop are NULL before the list is created.`

Comment: The problem where it skips the last element was explained in the comment by Alter Mann.  As for the reverse loop failing, my guess is that your logic for setting the `prev` pointers is buggy, but there's no way to diagnose the bug without actually seeing the code.

Comment: @Alter Mann Thanks, it worked! But why is my loop flawed? If 'current' is at the last but one position, current->next isn't NULL. Why doesn't it go to the last one?. Note: I replaced first with start for more clarity, as 'first' is a local variable used to transmit start to the function.

Comment: Just run through the loop where the list only has one element. `current->next!=NULL` is immediately false and the loop body does not execute even once.

Comment: @user2210558 Because at every iteration a loop executes the third part (in this case, `current=current->next`) and THEN it checks the condition, that is, the second part (`current->next!=NULL`). So with your code if you are at one before last you increase `current` (so it's the last), then you check the next element (which is NULL) and then it stops without printing the letter. If this order of evaluation of the parts of a `for` loop is confusing you, I'd suggest to consider a simpler one: `for(i=0;i<3;i++)`. First you have `i++`, then `i<3` is checked.

Comment: It looks like I forgot this elementary detail in the for loop. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for(current=start;current->next!=NULL;current=current->next)
              printf("%c",current->let);
```

to

```
for(current=start;current!=NULL;current=current->next)
              printf("%c",current->let);
```

Also change

```
for(current=stop;current->prev!=NULL;current=current->prev)
              printf("%c",current->let);
```

to

```
for(current=stop;current!=NULL;current=current->prev)
              printf("%c",current->let);
```

As `current->next!=NULL` and `current->prev!=NULL` will be false, and the loop will not even execute once.  Thus nothing will get printed as the `for` loop never executes.

To make it more clear, and understand how `for` loop works, see this flowchart:

[image]

You can also see [this](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-for-loop) tutorial for `for` loops.

You can also see the wiki article: [For loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)